# Meaning of Loose Coins in English

Tags: meaning

If coins are inside a wallet, are they loose or not? For example, if someone sees a wallet with coins inside a coin bag, and they are asked if they saw some loose coins, would the person be wrong if he/she answered "yes"?

Comment: The expression is actually *loose **change***, not  *loose coins*, and it really just means "coins" as opposed to paper money, regardless of where it's kept. The original sense of "loose" in the expression was more like "unrestrained" in the sense of "separated from the whole" and also maybe"not committed to a particular purpose", so figuratively small amounts of money that could be spent on whatever.

Comment: 1006a but when I say "loose coins" what comes to mind? Coins outside a container or bag, or simply coins that are not bound in a  paper roll?

Comment: The point is that nobody would normally *say* **loose coins**. If somebody said that to me, my first thought would be they were saying something strange. Then I would translate it in my head to **loose change** or **spare change**, which just means coins.

Comment: Reach into your pocket.  With your fingers sort out the key, the tissue, the ChapStick, and maybe (ICE permitting) that pocket knife.  Most of what remains is likely loose change/loose coins.

Comment: If you specifically said "have you seen any loose coins?" just out of the blue I might think you meant coins rolling down the sidewalk (like they had somehow *got loose* and we're now running free). Otherwise, I'd assume you meant "loose change" (which could, in fact, be kept in a wallet or bag or change purse). If you have a specific context in mind, or are trying to achieve a certain meaning, you might want to specify that in the question.

Comment: Then what term would you use for coins that are just laying on a table and not inside a pocket or a wallet or a bag or container of any kind?

Comment: Would spilled coins work for coins just laying on top of a table? Or would spilled coins also apply to coins inside a wallet, pocket, bag, jar, etc?

Comment: You could use something like "coins loose on the table" or "coins spilled across the table"—I think either of those would probably be more idiomatic, but that's getting into personal opinion/writing advice territory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In American usage, "loose coins" (as opposed  to "loose change") would likely be imagined as coins outside of a roll or coin purse. Loose change has a richer history of use; it would likely be applied to coins not in rolls or another precounted container such as a bag or box from a bank.

A writer might say something like "The wallet contained three tens and eighty two cent in loose change", but in the case where other coins were being accounted for, they might say "The bag had bundles of ones, a roll of nickels, and a few loose coins."

The feel difference for most people would be between the monetary value, and the coins as objects. In the first example, the important information is $10.82, the value of the money, whereas in the second, it's more like bundles and rolls, the fact that it's moeny, and not, say, a knife or the will or whatever.

Of course, this is highly subjective.

Comment: This comment by Hack Saw agrees with my intuitive understanding of loose coins as opposed to loose change. It seems like loose change has more history whereas loose coins just simply means coins found on tables or outside of coin purses, wallets, or piggybanks.